# ¿Como mostrar el nombre del usuario despues de iniciar sesion?

Tags: php

Buenas tardes amigos de la programación, esta vez vengo con un detalle, tengo un formulario de inicio de sesión y entro con el ID_usuario y el Pass, el cual accedo sin problemas, pero quiero que me muestre los siguientes datos del usuario que tengo en la tabla de la base de datos como el Nombre_usuario y el Tipo_Usuario, ahorita por lo pronto estoy tratando solo que me muestre el Nombre del usuario, en el archivo Principal.php tengo el código pero no se porque no me muestra el nombre ya que es ahí donde tengo ese pequeño problema o me estoy brincando al procedimiento o que me falte alguna código más.

**Principal.php**

```
<?php
  require_once("conexion.php");

  session_start();

   if (isset($_SESSION['ID_usuario'])) {
   header('location: Pdologin.php');
  } 

  $ideuser = $_SESSION['ID_usuario'];

  $sql = "SELECT Iduser, Nombre_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE Iduser = '$ideuser'";

  $result = $conexion->prepare($sql);

  $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="es">

 <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,     minimum-scale=1.0" />
<title>Principal</title>
</head>

<body>
<span>
    <small>Bienvenido</small>

    <?php echo utf8_decode($row ['Nombre_usuario']); ?>


  </span>
 </body>

</html>
```

**Pdologin.php**

```
<?php 
  require_once("conexion.php");
  session_start();

  if (isset($_SESSION['ID_usuario'])) {
  header('location: login.php');
  } 

  $errores ='';

  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $idusuario = filter_var (strtolower ($_POST['ID_usuario']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $pass = $_POST['Pass'];
    //$contraseña = hash('sha512', $contraseña);


    $statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM  usuarios  WHERE ID_usuario =:Idusuario  AND  Pass =:pass ');
    $statement->execute(array(':Idusuario' => $idusuario , ':pass' => $pass));
   
    $resultado = $statement ->fetch();
    
    if ($resultado !== false) {
        $_SESSION['ID_usuario'] = $usuario;
        header('location: Principal.php');
        
   }else {
       $errores .='<li>¡ Datos incorrectos verifique el usuario o contraseña !</li>';
    }  

   }

  require 'login.php'

 ?>
```

**Página principal**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Base de datos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Coloca un `var_dump($row);` en `Principal.php` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: Puede que, en parte, tu problema esté aquí: `$_SESSION['ID_usuario'] = $usuario;` ¿qué valor tiene `$usuario`  y dónde lo declaras? Además, ¿por qué haces dos `SELECT` sobre la misma tabla, en el Login y en Principal, acaso no es redundante un doble `SELECT`?

Comment: @A.Cedano  muestra lo siguiente bool(false) Bienvenido

Comment: Coloca ahora un  `var_dump( $conexion->errorInfo() );` para verificar si hay un error específico ya a ese nivel con respecto a la consulta.

Comment: @A.Cedano esto me arroja array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL } Bienvenido

Comment: Bueno, no parece haber error capturable ahí con respecto a PDO, háblanos de la variable `$usuario`  que asignas a la variable de sesión en el Login ¿? En Principal puede depurar tu variable de sesión completa con `var_dump($_SESSION);` , puede que el dato que usas para la consulta no exista, además, como señalé antes, no necesitas hacer la consulta SQL dos veces, puedes llenar la variable de sesión con los datos en la parte del Login.

Comment: @A.Cedano me arroja este resulatdo array(1) { ["ID_usuario"]=> NULL } Bienvenido

Comment: Es lo que te vengo diciendo, aquí asignas algo que no existe: `$_SESSION['ID_usuario'] = $usuario;` ¿De dónde sacas a `$usuario`? Explica un poco más tu contexto y agrega a la pregunta el archivo `login.php`. Pues pasas de un archivo a otro y no se entiende con claridad la forma que estás siguiendo para iniciar sesión, aparte de la redundancia ya referida.

Comment: Puedes usar el símbolo ` para resaltar el `código`. También tienes [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) una guía de cómo usar MD y html para dar formato a tu texto

Comment: Yo lo que veo aquí son unos errores en php que deben estar destrozando el resto del código, pero para ver eso debes de activar que se muestren los errores de php

Comment: @A.Cedano  respecto a esto $_SESSION['ID_usuario'] = $usuario ahi tuve un pequeño error es $idusuario

Comment: es la que me manda a la página principal

Comment: ¿Qué muestran los var_dump una vez corregido?

Comment: @A.Cedano para poner un solo  `select` eso seria ahi en el Pdologin.php, ya que quite el codigo de php de la pagina principal.